# Javascript to transform on both X and Y axis (CSS 3D)

Tags: javascript, css, transform, tween

I am using tween to rotate on both X and Y axis. But I cant seem to find the correct javascript to edit the css.

Target is a div, and with the following code, it only rotates the axis while ignoring the Y axis.

It uses Tween JS

```
function update() {

    target.style.left = position.x + 'px';
    target.style.top = position.y + 'px';
    target.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + Math.floor(position.rotation) + 'deg)';
    target.style.MozTransform = 'rotateY(' + Math.floor(position.rotation) + 'deg)';
    target.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateX(' + Math.floor(position.rotation) + 'deg)';
    target.style.MozTransform = 'rotateY(' + Math.floor(position.rotation) + 'deg)';

}
```

How do I tell javascript to rotate on both and not just one axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You separate arguments with spaces. For example:

```
target.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateX(' + Math.floor(rotationX) + 'deg) rotateY(' + Math.floor(rotationY) + 'deg)';
```

(If you change the same property twice, you'll only overwrite previous value.)